Keyboard overlapping entry control in .NET MAUI - .NET 8 (Android)
Does anyone know how can I implement the soft keyboard on Android .NET MAUI?
I tried doing like it's said in the docs and in stack overflow forums, but nothing seemed to work.
Whatever I do, my keyboard is overlapping the entries from the bottom of the screen.
Does anyone have a workaround this on Android with .NET 8 ?

Accordind to Soft keyboard input mode on Android, you can try to set the WindowSoftInputModeAdjust as Pan in your App.xaml like below. The Pan value uses the AdjustPan adjustment option, which doesn't resize the window when an input control has focus. Instead, the contents of the window are panned so that the current focus isn't obscured by the soft keyboard
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan">
  ...
</Application>


I have tried this already, but it does not seem to work. I tried it with a scrollview. Do you have any idea what could I've done wrong? I think that

@AlexandruCracea Thanks for your response, you can also use Hide Keyboard using CommunityToolkit.Maui nuget package. Also, please help create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  and add it to your post.
